# Graph for perf4j on per request basis

Tags: java, log4j, perf4j

I am trying to plot the graph along with the log file of it.
The graph is being plotted but in the perf4j log file it asks for the updates even when the the count is 0. How can it be stopped. Moreover if I want to plot the graph on per request basis on the browser, Can it be done and how?

Thank You